# Full width html body on tablet

Tags: html, css

**Basic Question**

How do I get a website to be width:100% on tablet devices.

There are java-script options to detect screen size and readjust the CSS accordingly. If this is currently the only option I will accept that, but surely with HTML5/CSS3 there is a more elegant solution.

**To elaborate:**

I'm not worried about mobile devices, because the app is so detailed, The mobile version has to have simpler options.

The problem has come because tablets now come in high definition. So designing a site for max-width:998px was fine in the past, a tablet with full HD will not display as 100% width because obviously it will be greater than 998px.

I have looked into zoom, but the consensus is it's not really supported yet.

**Finally**

Should I start designing my pages to fit max-width:1280px, and have my forms/tables width:100%?

At the moment I'm using http://getbootstrap.com/ and it's amazing, but doesn't have a tablet detection library. I have classes for different sized devices, but it'd like to say, tablet=width 100%.

**Final note**

In case it's unclear most examples follow `<body><div class="container">...</div></body>` So I'm after the `.container` to be 100% width on a tablet.

I'm currently 100% up to 998px, but might have to increase that to 1200px, feedback on that too would be nice.

**Edit 1**

I got a vote for too broad. Could you please elaborate because I've been searching for weeks before I posted. There is very little on how to create a full width tablet website. If you want examples I can create some pages. The problem is so many different resolutions. An example, I want to have a page or form with account/contact details and have it fit any size tablet, on a desktop if I open the page on a 50 inch screen it won't work if the inputs are width:percent. Why it is limited to max-width:998px, to try fit most desktops. But tablets, despite the resolution, are small screens, and will look perfect full width.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`..
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: and YES to the question about 100% width containers (with a set max-widt). And don¡'t forget to add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: Thank you. When I referred to zoom I should have said scale too. As per your reference "The width property controls the size of the viewport." So I would assume if you had width=device-width as per the example .container:width:100% would always be 100%. But that doesn't solve mobile or desktop changes..

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez Is your response from experience? As I said if I set width 100% up to 998 or even 1200 that doesn't solve my question because I want it 100% on tablets. When you rotate a tablet it becomes smaller than a desktop so CSS gets confused..

Comment: @BradleyForster If you use a combination of `width: 100%` and `max-width: 1200px;` you probably won't have problems with devices smaller than 1200px because it will only stretch to 100%.

Comment: Yes, from my own experience. I am making around 3 web pages a month (sometimes more sometimes less depending on the size of the project). And improving everyday. My max-width use to be 1180px which allows a nice display in old not panoramic monitors keeping margins and I recomend the use of many css @media steps. Minimum steps I recomend are 3: around 980px, 760px and 480px.

Comment: But then, even with an easy project, You may test your web once "live" on as many platforms as possible, don't trust too much mobile and tablets emulators, and you may slightly change those steps which would take just a minute asuming your css sheet is well organized. Good luck with your project (and don't forget the meta tag)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, it has the detection for it.

Go into the css and check for the comments, ull find something like:

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }
```

It is full-width by default, but the containers have some margins, but nothing to worry about, you can always override those classes or make a custom stylesheet with

[customize your bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

If you want to do it manually, a full width for tablet is as easy as set your `container` div at `width:100%`

My advice: Custom the margin on the `.container` on boostrap (and maybe the cols as well) to have fully width template.